# Full training set used by dask_lightgbm?

Tags: dask, lightgbm

I'm reading over the implementation of the [dask-lightgbm](https://github.com/dask/dask-lightgbm) estimators (specifically, the `_train_part` function in dask_lightgb.core.py), and I'm failing to see how the entirety of the training set gets used to fit the final estimator?

The `_train_part` function accepts the boolean argument `return_model`, and in the implementation of the `train` function (which uses `client.submit` to call `_train_part` on each worker), `return_model` is only true when the worker is the "master_worker" (which itself appears to be a randomly chosen Dask worker). Logically, each worker gets dispatched 1/n chunks of the overall model training set - where n = total number of workers - then each worker trains its own independent model on its own subset of the training set. The `return_model` parameter controls whether each worker's model gets returned by `_train_part`, so it returns None for all workers - and therefore, models - except for one worker.

Code:

```py
def _train_part(params, model_factory, list_of_parts, worker_addresses, return_model, local_listen_port=12400,
                time_out=120, **kwargs):

    network_params = build_network_params(worker_addresses, get_worker().address, local_listen_port, time_out)
    params.update(network_params)

    # Concatenate many parts into one
    parts = tuple(zip(*list_of_parts))
    data = concat(parts[0])
    label = concat(parts[1])
    weight = concat(parts[2]) if len(parts) == 3 else None

    try:
        model = model_factory(**params)
        model.fit(data, label, sample_weight=weight)
    finally:
        _safe_call(_LIB.LGBM_NetworkFree())

    return model if return_model else None
```

Is this not equivalent to training a non-distributed version of a lightgbm estimator on a 1/n subsample of the training set? Am I missing something? I feel like I am missing a part where either the workers' independent models get combined into one, or where a single estimator is getting updated with the individual trees learned by separate workers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ah the answer is yes - dask_lightgbm uses all available training samples. Dask's responsibility is only to distribute data across workers. LightGBM handles all distributed learning once its [network parameters](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#network-parameters) are set. It's not that each worker is training its own independent model - LightGBM is training a single model - but each worker will get a copy of it. For this reason, only the chosen worker returns the fitted estimator, and everyone else returns None.